# How to sort data in a Table View by the order in which they were saved?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, uitableview, sorting

I have a Table View in Xcode that is being populated by information that the user of the application is saving to iCloud. So my problem here is that whenever the user does save their data the data that is saved is being added to the every bottom of the table view of data instead of at the top which is where I want it to be seen once it has been saved.The data that is being saved is being saved to an array which then populates the Table View, but I am not sure how to sort the array due to the fact new data is being added to it every so often. Here is the code for the array in which i am working with:

```
- (NSArray *)notes
{
    if (_notes) {
        return _notes;
    }

    _notes = [[[NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore defaultStore] arrayForKey:@"AVAILABLE_NOTES"] mutableCopy];
    if (!_notes) _notes = [NSMutableArray array];

    return _notes;
}
```

and the data is being saved by this action here:

```
- (IBAction)save:(id)sender {


    // Notify the previouse view to save the changes locally
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"New Note" object:self userInfo:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:self.finalScore.text forKey:@"Note"]];

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];


}
```

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like _notes is the array you need to sort before returning in the notes method.

Comment: The problem is sorting the existing data? or adding a new data to the top?

Comment: The problem is sorting any existing data.

Answer (score 0):

You can store an object to the array that includes a date/time (along with your note data) - you can then sort the array by that value to get them in created order or reverse created order.

The other option might be since items are always added at the end, simply read the array in reverse order when displaying in the table. This may be helpful:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/reverseObjectEnumerator

In fact, look at all the methods on NSArray - some really good and useful stuff there.

Hope this helps.